# ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly (cl was not found in PATH)

Tags: python, c++, opencv, cmake

I was trying to install opencv-python in visual studio (with Visual Studio 2019 installed) but kept coming up with this error. I have tried most of the methods that were previously posted regarding this PEP517 error but i am still getting errors. Appreciate if someone could help me out here as i am just a beginner coder. Thanks alot in advance.

Below is the error code:

```
$ pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.4.0.44.tar.gz (88.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.19.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
  Building wheel for opencv-python (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python\python.exe' 'c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Austen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6zo4yrsx'
       cwd: C:\Users\Austen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tcb_5anh\opencv-python
  Complete output (153 lines):
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Austen/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-tcb_5anh/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Austen/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-tcb_5anh/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

  ********************************************************************************
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using? It used to be very picky about which compiler to build extensions with.

Comment: Hi, i’m currently using the latest version of python (v3.9)

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully resolved this error issue. There are two methods of going about it, you can use either:

1. Downgrading Python 3.9 to Python 3.8
2. Use conda instead of pip (if you have python 3.9 installed and don't want to downgrade)

Cheers!